# Uninstall Magento extension Creativestyle_CheckoutByAmazon via Admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to install the following extension via Magento Connect 2.0

```
Creativestyle_CheckoutByAmazon
```

My issue is that I need to uninstall this extension first as it already exists (seems to be partially broken so I want to reinstall it) - what is the best method for uninstalling extensions in Magento, is there a simple option for this in Magento Admin?

For some reason I have logged into my Magento Connect but cannot see any of my installed modules - see link below..

http://postimg.org/image/5n9vbyipf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever module you have installed, will be having its module file in app/etc/modules folder.
You can set false in `<active>false</active>` tags in the repective xml file.  Also, you can extract the module's zip and replaced all the old ones with the new default files.